# How do I save a model with this dynamically generated field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails model that looks something like this:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :ingredients
   attr_accessor :ingredients_string
   attr_accessible :title, :directions, :ingredients, :ingredients_string

   before_save :set_ingredients

   def ingredients_string
      ingredients.join("\n")
   end

   private

   def set_ingredients
      self.ingredients.each { |x| x.destroy }
      self.ingredients_string ||= false
      if self.ingredients_string
         self.ingredients_string.split("\n").each do |x|
            ingredient = Ingredient.create(:ingredient_string => x)
            self.ingredients << ingredient
         end
      end
   end
end
```

The idea is that when I create the ingredient from the webpage, I pass in the `ingredients_string` and let the model sort it all out. Of course, if I am editing an ingredient I need to re-create that string. The bug is basically this: how do I inform the view of the ingredient_string (elegantly) and still check to see if the `ingredient_string` is defined in the `set_ingredients` method?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand what you're asking. What is the problem you're trying to solve? Can you give an example of how it is used and where it breaks down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using these two together are probably causing your issues.  Both are trying to define an `ingredients_string` method that do different things

```
   attr_accessor :ingredients_string

   def ingredients_string
      ingredients.join("\n")
   end
```

Get rid of the `attr_accessor`, the `before_save`, `set_ingredients` method and define your own `ingredients_string=` method, something like this:

```
def ingredients_string=(ingredients)
    ingredients.each { |x| x.destroy }
    ingredients_string ||= false
    if ingredients_string
        ingredients_string.split("\n").each do |x|
            ingredient = Ingredient.create(:ingredient_string => x)
            self.ingredients << ingredient
        end
    end
end
```

Note I just borrowed your implementation of `set_ingredients`.  There's probably a more elegant way to break up that string and create/delete Ingredient model associations as needed, but it's late and I can't think of it right now. :)

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is very good but it could do with a few changes.

def ingredients_string=(text)
    ingredients.each { |x| x.destroy }
    unless text.blank?
        text.split("\n").each do |x|
            ingredient = Ingredient.find_or_create_by_ingredient_string(:ingredient_string => x)
            self.ingredients

Comment: Well, this isn't actually a find_or_create_by situation.  Ingredients are unique.  IngredientTypes, otoh, are not unique, and they are set up with a find_or_create_by method.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I basically just modified Otto's answer:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :ingredients
   attr_accessible :title, :directions, :ingredients, :ingredients_string

   def ingredients_string=(ingredient_string)
      ingredient_string ||= false
      if ingredient_string
         self.ingredients.each { |x| x.destroy }
         unless ingredient_string.blank?
            ingredient_string.split("\n").each do |x|
               ingredient = Ingredient.create(:ingredient_string => x)
               self.ingredients << ingredient
            end
         end
      end
   end

   def ingredients_string
      ingredients.join("\n")
   end

end
```